# Prove by Induction that $2^n \geq n+12$ for all $n\geq4$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, logic, induction, exponential-function

> Prove by induction that $$2^n \geq n+12$$ 
>   for all $n\geq4.$

Not sure how to proceed with this question. If someone could answer it in a step by step induction process (base step, induction hypothesis, induction step), I'd very much appreciate it.

Comment: Did you try the base step?

Comment: yeah i just plugged in 4

Comment: For the induction step, let p=n+1, substitute in n=p-1 into your equation and try to show the same equation for p

Comment: For large enough $n$ you have $2^n$ greater than any polynomial even if it has degree one billion or one googol or more.

Comment: If you plugged in $4$ yourself, you really need not ask for help with the base step.

Answer (score 2):

Well you've already got the good idea of using induction. So your start is to pick the lowest $n$ you can ($4$) in this case, and seeing if it works for that.

Assuming it does, why don't we try extending it, see if we can somehow prove it works for $n+1$?

Doing that will complete the proof.

Comment: Oh ok well I got to the inductive step and made n=k+1. I get 2^(k+1) >= (k+1)+12. I guess my real question is how I prove it from there. Not sure how far I simplify

Answer (score 2):

For $n=4$ it's obvious.

Let $2^n\geq n+12$ for any $n\geq4$.

Thus, $$2^{n+1}=2\cdot2^n\geq2(n+12)=n+1+12+n+11>(n+1)+12$$ and by induction we are done!

Comment: can you please explain how you get n+1+12+n+11 > (n+1) +12 at the end? I'm not really sure how to get there from the last step

Comment: @Nihal Mandava $2(n+12)=2n+24=(n+1)+12+n+11>(n+1)+12$ because $n+11>0$.

Comment: @NihalMandava since $2^n \geq n+12\quad2(2^n) \geq 2(n+12) > (n+1)+12 $

Comment: oh ok i see now. Thanks for explaining!

Comment: @Nihal Mandava You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Define the functions $f(n) = 2^n$ and $g(n) = n + 12$. If we look at the difference between consecutive $n$ for the functions, i.e.:

$$f(n+1) - f(n) = 2^{n+1} - 2^n = 2^n$$ $$g(n+1)-g(n) = (n+1) + 12 - (n+12) = 1$$

We can clearly see that $f(n)$ grows with $2^n$ between each term as $n$ increments, and $g(n)$ grows by $1$ between each term as $n$ increments.

Solving for $n$ in $2^n = n + 12$ we find that they are equal at $n = 4$. However $f(n)$ will grow exponentially faster than $g(x)$; so after $n=4$, $f(x)$ will always be larger than $g(x)$.